# How to remove The Red 'Error' Text and the Exclamation mark from apex page message

Tags: pagemessages, apexpage, page-messages

I want to remove the red 'Error' text and the exclamation mark from apex page message and want to show only the Message. Please see image below:

[image]

Providing sample code for reference:

**Page:**

```xml
<apex:page controller="Cntl_ApexMessageTest" >    
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:inputText value="{!val}" html-placeholder="Enter value" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!submit}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller:**

```java
public class Cntl_ApexMessageTest {
    public integer val {set; get;}
    public Cntl_ApexMessageTest () {    
    }

    public void submit() {
        if(Math.mod(val,2) == 0){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM,'You have provided an even number!'));
        } else {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Please provide an even number!'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's inbuilt. I don't think you can remove that unless you opt for custom validation using bootstrap

Comment: @NITHESH I checked the link.. There apex:message used to statically show the message.. But I want to use apex:messages to dynamically show the message (setting from controller). Can we dynamically set message using apex:message? Pls explain with an example..

Comment: No, you have to create your own css style and apply.

Comment: @NITHESHK Yeah I believe I have to build using css+jquery etc.. Thanks for your advice :)